# How to fix View [app] not found in Laravel version 4.4.0

Tags: php, view, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I tried to run my laravel project on a local server and it says "app was not found".
"Are you sure the view exists and is a `.blade.php` file?" even though my view exist as well as it is a blade.php file.

I run php artisan serve with a local host of [http://127.0.0.1:8000]
Then I tried to access the login.blade.php I created in http://127.0.0.1:8000/login where I got the View [app] not found error.
I rechecked my views, controllers and routes but the problem is still there. I hope someone can help me on this.

[here is the view of my files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSW85.png)

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard')
                ->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }

        return redirect('login')->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }

    public function registration()
    {
        return view('auth.registration');
    }

    public function customRegistration(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        $data = $request->all();
        $check = $this->create($data);

        return redirect('dashboard')->withSuccess('You have signed-in');
    }

    public function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ]);
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return view('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect('login')->withSuccess('You are not allowed to access');
    }

    public function signOut()
    {
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect('login');
    }
}
```

```html
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<main class="login-form">
    <div class="cotainer">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <h3 class="card-header text-center">Login</h3>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login.custom') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required
                                    autofocus>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-grid mx-auto">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Signin</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
@endsection
```

```html
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<main class="signup-form">
    <div class="cotainer">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <h3 class="card-header text-center">Register User</h3>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('register.custom') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" class="form-control" name="name"
                                    required autofocus>
                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email_address" class="form-control"
                                    name="email" required autofocus>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control"
                                    name="password" required>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-grid mx-auto">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Sign up</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
@endsection
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Auth in Laravel</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg mb-5" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">PositronX</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    @guest
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register-user') }}">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    @else
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('signout') }}">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    @endguest
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomAuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::get('dashboard', [CustomAuthController::class, 'dashboard']);
Route::get('login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('custom-login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customLogin'])->name('login.custom');
Route::get('registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'registration'])->name('register-user');
Route::post('custom-registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customRegistration'])->name('register.custom');
Route::get('signout', [CustomAuthController::class, 'signOut'])->name('signout');
```

Comment: Which one is your `@extends('app')`? In the `views` folder there is no `app.blade.php`

Comment: @iamafish I have no app.blade.php file in my view folder. Can you please elaborate what should I do? I don't know how @extends('') works.

Comment: @iamafish I tried to change @extends('app') to @extends('dashboard') and it works. Thank you for mentioning that my @extends('app') is missing because of that I finally understand whats wrong with my code.